# Asp.Net Master Pages and TreeViews

Tags: asp.net

I am having a problem with master pages that I hope you can help.
I have a Master Page that contains a TreeView, I have a .aspx page "Home Page" that will show the data based on selection made on TreeView. When the program runs for the first time it goes to Default page where user needs to make a selection on the TreeView once the selection has been made it takes them to Home Page and I send the selection via session variable. The only problem now is when the user is already under a Home Page and they select a new item in the TreeView I am unable to get the selection made because Home Page refreshes first then loads the master page.

Do you guys know of any other way to get around this or would suggest doing it differently.

Let me know if I need to clarify this better.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: can you post the html & code?

Comment: There is a lot of code over 200 lines in master page. Would you might know the best route to approach this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do both pages Default and Homepage use the same master page? Does this treeview appears on every page ?

Comment: There are actually two master pages (Nested Master Pages). First master page is used for Navigation only and the second master page has a TreeView. The TreeView master page is the nested page of Navigation Master Page. Default.aspx and Home.aspx both use the TreeView Master Page. The tree view will not appear on every page once the Home.aspx displays data they will have a choice on clicking onto data where it will take them to another form for Data Viewing or Data Entry, Dashboard... those pages will not have the treeview it will only show the navigation tabs.